# Where in the world are are the HTML nesting rules?

Tags: html, validation

Can someone provide a link to a document that has all HTML (preferably HTML5) nesting rules?

For example: you can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're just trying to learn the rules, I suggest that you use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) rather than trying to read a stuffy spec. Validating my code at different stages is what helped me learn (since it pointed out the mistakes I was making).

Comment: True, but I want to know specifically without trial and error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). Take, for example, [the p element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

The Content Model will tell you what it can contain. In this case: "Phrasing content.", which links to a list of elements interspersed with exceptions.

Comment: Right, I see that... But where does it specify what elements are allowed to be nested inside of a p element? That's what I'm looking for. EDIT... aaah, phrasing content. Perfect, thanks. :)

Comment: Does the spec include an easy way to see the expected parent content model? That is, how can you tell that a <p> can be in a <body> rather than being required to be inside an element from a particular category? I haven't found an easy way to read that in the spec. Specifically, for <img>, the spec says: "Contexts in which this element can be used: Where embedded content is expected." but the section on "embedded content" doesn't say which category the parent element must be.

Comment: @Elisabeth That's a good question.

Answer (score 5):

Not. Html5, but http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nesting.html is a useful list in the form I think you want.  Absurdly complicated....

Comment: That's neat. An updated one for HTML5 would be nice.

Comment: link rot, and not archived.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) the link to the xhtml 1 spec.

Comment: And here to the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html).

Comment: Advising xhtml1 is a little... ...dated, eh?  Or did you mention it only because it is more likely to be explicit about nesting.

Comment: This was tagged with "xhtml-1.0-strict"...

Comment: @Tchalvak - See Dietrich Epp's comment.

Comment: True, sorry about that, it is outdated. I've updated my question. I'd rather know about HTML 5 specifically.

Comment: So, for example, I see < !ELEMENT p %Inline; > for paragraphs in the xhtml1.0 spec, but I don't see what elements are allowed to be nested inside p elements...

Comment: You have to cross-reference the definition of %Inline.